# Flag first year within a group in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame structured as follows:

```
+----------+------+
| ID       | year |
+----------+------+
| 1        | 2002 |
| 1        | 2003 |
| 1        | 2004 |
| 2        | 2015 |
| 2        | 2016 |
| 2        | 2017 |
| 2        | 2018 |
| 3        | 2004 |
| 3        | 2005 |
+----------+------+
```

I would like to add a variable which flags the first (or earliest) occurrence within ID to get the following:

```
+----------+------+------+
| ID       | year | flag | 
+----------+------+------+
| 1        | 2002 | 1    |
| 1        | 2003 | 0    | 
| 1        | 2004 | 0    |
| 2        | 2015 | 1    |
| 2        | 2016 | 0    |
| 2        | 2017 | 0    |
| 2        | 2018 | 0    |
| 3        | 2004 | 1    | 
| 3        | 2005 | 0    |
+----------+------+------+
```

Is there an easy way to do this in dplyr?

Answer (score 4):

With `dplyr`, we can group by 'ID' and create a logical vector based on the `min` value of 'year', coerce it to binary with `+`

```
df1 %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   mutate(flag = +(year == min(year))
```

If the data is already `order`ed

```
df1 %>%
    mutate(flag = !duplicated(ID))
```

---

Or if the 'year' is already `order`ed

```
df1$flag <- !duplicated(df1$ID)
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another base R option using `ave`

```
transform(
  df,
  flag = ave(1:nrow(df),ID, FUN = function(x) seq_along(x)==1)
)
```